# EmberJS шаблоны

Tags: ember.js, шаблоны

Добрый день.

Если я все правильно понимаю, в emberJs по дефолту подразумевается, что в моем конечном html хранятся все шаблоны (handlebares). Т. е. юзер открыл главную страницу, а ему сразу подгрузились все возможные шаблоны. Меня это немного смущает. Кто в курсе, объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это действительно так. Это очень не удобно особенно когда шаблонов таких больше чем с десяток. Но никто не мешает использовать requirejs с их плагином [text](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text). Который позволит подгружать шаблоны по мере необходимости. Тут конечно тоже недостаток, придется рефакторить проект.

Answer (score 0):

ну шаблоны хранятся в конечном js файле... шаблоны компилируются из htmlbars (шаблоны Ember.js)... можно можна настроить свою зборку например з webpack вот пример https://github.com/pit-rpg/WebPack-Ember-Express .. тогда можна подгружать компоненты, шаблоны, стили, по надобности с помощу webpack require ensure, также он поддерживает AMD подгрузку и нодовский стиль.. и т.д...